# Achieving Closure in C

Tags: c, closures

I am essentially trying to replicate C#'s Linq's functionality in C.

In C# the code would look like this

```
// main
Coordinate coord = new Coordinate { x = 0, y = 0};
bool result = coordinates.Any(c => c.Data.Y == coord.Y || c.Data.X == coord.X);
```

In C, I have gotten this far:

```
int any(struct linked_list *list, int (*cb)(struct node *node))
{
    .....
    do
    {
    if (cb)
        if ((*cb)(pNode))
            return 1;
    pNode = pNode->next;
    } while (pNode);
    return 0;
}

int compareCoordinates(struct node *node, struct coordinate *coord)
{
    struct coordinate *iterator = node->data;
    return iterator->x == coord->x || iterator->y == coord->y;
}
// main
struct coordinate coord;
int result = any(coordinates,compareCoordinates(??, coord));
```

I realize that it doesn't make much sense to pass two arguments into a function with one parameter, but from my knowledge, arguments get added to the stack before the function is called, so I figure there must be a way to have access to both.. I'm learning C for fun and I'm not sure exactly what to Google as this is something I've never done before.  I figure if the Linq library can make it happen in C#, then it should be possible in C. Is there another way to access local variables from your callback?

EDIT: After some more research, I realized I could achieve what I want with nested functions, although I am still curious as to see if you can pass more to a function than the signature states.

Comment: You can create a variadic function (such as `printf`) with `stdarg`.  But you have to access the arguments in sequence, and you have to know what type was passed before you can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically nest function definitions in GNU C (note that isn't a closure, as it won't keep `coord` around after the parent function returns):

```
int main(void) {
  struct coordinate coord;

  int compareCoordinates(struct node *node) {
    ...
  };

  any(list, compareCoordinates);
}
```

..but you really shouldn't (non-portable behavior). A normal `for` loop is simpler, faster, and easier to read, as tempting as the trappings of such a higher-order function is.

In C++11 and up, on the other hand, you could get closer to the original C# pattern with a lambda:

```
any(list, [](struct node *node) -> bool { ... });
```

Comment: GNU C does not support closures.  It does permit nested functions, but any up-level references are only valid as long as the function frame is active.  As soon as it returns, the results become undefined (as compared to a closure, in which the frame is preserved for as long as there are any active references to it).

Comment: Fair point, but that's not an issue for this case (the function isn't stored anywhere else in `any`)

Comment: It would typically arise if the function returned a pointer to its own nested function, and the nested function references variables in its parent.  In that case, the parent function's frame needs to be kept.  That's why closures result in a call tree rather than a call stack.

Comment: Are nested functions exclusive to GNU C? Do you recommend I get out of the C# mentality and simply enumerate the linked list into an array and compare it that way? 

EDIT: I did go about it using nested functions, but your comment has me a little worried, I'd favor standardization over familiarity, and will definitely change it

Comment: @MustafaAbdul-Kader Nested functions are unique to GNU C as far as I know. And yeah, you should just iterate over it like normal. Higher-order functions aren't really idiomatic to C -- any attempt to make one will probably end up uglier than a normal loop, unlike the C# one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, so I don't really understand what

```
bool result = coordinates.Any(c => c.Data.Y == coord.Y || c.Data.X == coord.X);
```

does. But looking at your C code tells me that you are using a function pointer,
the second argument `cb` is a function pointer.

I don't know if you really understand function pointers, so I'm going to explain
it quickly: A pointer is a variable that stores the address of memory location,
this can be the address of another variable or the address from dynamically
allocated memory through `malloc`.

C doesn't have *call-by-reference*, it's always *call-by-value*, meaning that
the arguments of a function are always copies of the original. By passing
pointers it's possible to emulate *call-by-reference*, because the function
getting the pointer can access the original memory through the pointer.

There are also another kind of pointers: function pointers. These are like
regular pointers but they store the location of a function. You usually use them
for callback mechanism, for example the [`qsort`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function takes a function
pointer to a `compare` function which is provided by the user. With this,
`qsort` is able to sort any kind of arrays.

If you want that `compareCoordinates` also has access to another variable, then
you have to pass that variable to the function calling `compareCoordinates`.

So, you can rewrite the `any` function like this:

```
int any(struct linked_list *list, struct coordinate *coord, int (*cb)(struct node*, struct coordinate*))
{
    ....
    do
    {
        if (cb)
            if(cb(pNode, coord))
                return 1;
        pNode = pNode->next;
    } while (pNode);

    return 0;
}

// this function didn't change
int compareCoordinates(struct node *node, struct coordinate *coord)
{
    struct coordinate *iterator = node->data;
    return iterator->x == coord->x || iterator->y == coord->y;
}

// in main
int main(void)
{
    ...
    struct coordinate coord;
    // here you should initialize coord (unless you do that in
    // the any function. It's not clear from your snippet

    int result = any(coordinates, &coord, compareCoordinates);

    ...
}
```

First take a look at function `any`. To use a function pointer, you don't need to
dereference it (meaning using `*`-operator). I also changed the declaration of `cb`,
so that it matches with `compareCoordinates`. Also `any` takes one more
argument: a pointer to a `strcut coordinate`.

Now when you want to call `any`, you have to pass the 3 parameters: the list,
a pointer to a `struct coordinate` (the `&`-operator returns the address of a variable)
and the function you want `any` to call for the comparison. Note that in order
to pass a function to another function, you only have to use the name.

One last thing: `struct coordinate coord;` only declares the variable, it is not
initialized. At some point you have to initialize it.

**edit**

another little thing: when you declare a function pointer, you don't need to
name the arguments. You can do it if you want, but it is not necessary.

```
int (*func1)(int a, int b, int c);  // that's fine

int (*func1)(int, int, int); // that's also correct
```

I prefer the second one, you have to type less and it increases (at least for me)
the readability of the code.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on the whole nature of whether or not function pointers best practice is to dereference it or not. It compiles both ways, and it helps me remember it's a pointer. If it's not standard, I'll definitely make sure to omit it next time. I do appreciate your tip about function pointers not needing named arguments, I didn't know that! It also makes me feels more at home as it's almost similar to C#. Regarding the    "struct coordinate coord;" it was for example's sake, yet doesn't the declaration of a struct initialize the values inside to their default value -- in which case..

Comment: both x and y are 0? Sorry these comments respond to your post all over the place, I appreciate your thoroughness and insights. (fyi, I did manage to get what I wanted to solved with nested functions!)

Comment: @MustafaAbdul-Kader You can dereference a function pointer to a function that returns a pointer, I'm surprised you could compile it. The way you call it in your question is definitively a syntax error. The way I rewrote the function is the way many of the functions in the standard library do: see the link to `qsort`. C doesn't have closures, so you have to pass your "closure-variable" every time. to be continued...

Comment: *yet doesn't the declaration of a struct initialize the values inside to their default value*, no if you don't **explicitly** initialize a struct, `x` and `y` will be undefined, they might be 0 but they also might be 10019282 or -123828. Global variables are initialized with 0 because they reside in a different part of the binary, but that is certainly not the case for variables in the scope of a function.